# Can't call smart contract from Python

Tags: python, smartcontracts, algorand

I'm trying to call an Algorand smart contract from with python.

[image]

I can't get my private key using mnemonic why that?

I'm using Python and I'm trying this command:

```
private_key = algosdk.mnemonic.to_private_key('word1, word2, word3, etc...)
```

it does not work.

would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's super simple, don't put commas between the words.